# Given $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ find the following and state if the composite function exists

Tags: functions

This is a two part question. I want to **find the following and determine whether or not the composite functions exist.** I'm fairly sure of my functions, but I would like to confirm that they are correct as well as my conclusions about whether or not they exist.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true if you consider real field.